# с++ question new delete

Tags: c++, syntax, memory-leaks

I have the following code

```
void foo()
{
    char* pcBlock = new char[1000];
    ...
    delete[] pcBlock;
    ...
    pcBlock = new char[100000];
    ...
    delete[] pcBlock;
}
```

Would the code below result in a memory leak?

```
void foo()
{
    char* pcBlock = new char[1000];
    ...
    pcBlock = new char[100000];
    ...
    delete[] pcBlock;
}
```

Comment: Use a std::string or  std::vector<char> and say goodbye to manual memory management and memory leaks.

Comment: @unapersson there are many good reasons NOT TO use std::vector/std::string for some uses.

Comment: Fixed-size buffers for some uses. Not wanting to write custom STL allocators (and dissatisfied with default use). Good STL implementation unavailable on target system.

Comment: @jv42 The OP is asking about dynamically creating arrays, which is what string and vector do. I've never written a custom allocator and never expect to, and any STL that can't  manage to implement string and vector is broken, as is the compiler implementation that contains it. I don't think these can be classed as either "many" or commmon problems.

Comment: Well, that's your perception of the world. Mine differs. I had to write custom allocators, I had to dynamically create buffers, I know of problems with default STL implementations on some systems, see http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2271.html for instance.

Comment: @jv42 I find it amusing that the link you posted is for an STL replacement that among other things implements vector.

Comment: I'll stop here, too close to trolling for my own taste.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there's likely a memory leak if you don't `delete[] pcBlock` in the first `...`. Reassigning a pointer does not automatically delete what it previously pointed to.

Answer (score 2):

Operator "new" and "delete" should be used in pairs. Otherwise, using "new" without "deleting" causes memory leakage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the previously allocated 1000 bytes are not freed and pcBlock is replaced with new set of memory. There is no way to release the previous 1000 bytes. So its a mem leak.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will most likely leak memory (unless the compiler is smart enough to fix that for you, but most won't).

Maybe you should try to [realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/) in some way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will. Probably you think that the arrays will overlap and delete therefore will free the first array, but in fact they are allocated to different parts of memory.

Answer (score 0):

YES IT WOULD CAUSE MEMORY LEAK

---

In C++ there is one simple rule:
Every call of `new` should end with call of `delete` at the end.
And every `new[]` -> with `delete[]`. Otherwise you will get memory leak.
C++ is language where programmer should control dynamic memory by himself (or using 3rd-party libs).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: @Wins ok, the answer is YES. Now you are happy?

Comment: It's not about whether I'm happy or not. StackOverflow is about asking and answering. If someone asks a questions, it means he/she really needs to have answer that: 1) help him/her to solve the problem, or 2) help him/her to understand the reason behind the answer. But more importantly, he/she will need to know the definitive answer to yes/no, true/false questions.

Comment: @Wins well in my answer I explained reasons why this happening. And for me, reasons are much more useful rather then just yes or no. Resons make you think, not just know something.